# A difficult proof about integers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let be N a nonnegative integer.

Can it be proven that there are infinitely many N such that

$N+20=s^2\cdot p$ and

$N+19=q^2\cdot (2\cdot p+1)$

with q and s integers >1 and p and $(2\cdot p+1)$ prime?

Comment: This question is better suited to math.stackexchange. Also, if it’s a homework problem then you should say that.

Comment: It shouldn't just be migrated to MSE, though; you need to show some effort at the solution, or at least explain some motivation.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many solutions with the prime $p:=5$ (in which case $2p+1=11$ is also prime).

It is known that the Pell equation $u^2-55v^2=1$ has infinitely many solutions in positive integers. Let $(u,v)$ be any solution. Then $s:=3u+22v$ and $t:=2u+15v$ satisfy $5s^2-11q^2=1$, hence $N:=5s^2-20$ satisfies both $N+20=5s^2$ and $N+19=11q^2$. Done.

Comment: Nice answer but the question was clearly from homework or maybe a take home exam.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: Maybe, but this problem is aesthetically and intellectually unpleasing. I mean, it is ugly and dull, especially the $N+20$ vs. $N+19$ part. My exam problems are beautiful, even more than my homework problems.